# Exclude overwrite for whitespace when in overwrite mode in Notepad++

Tags: insert, notepad++, whitespace, overwrite

Is there a way to stay in the overwrite mode of Notepad++ but still use the whitespace character (space key) as if it is in the insert mode?

Comment: Don't think so. Tab works to align text, but that's about it. What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Can you share some more information?

Comment: It's more comfortable to work in overwrite mode, but it's quite annoying when there is the need to put a space, because you need to switch to the insert mode.
So I was just wondering if there is any way to avoid this

Comment: Space(s) are input during overwrite mode, not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean create an exception for this char. For example tabs behave like if it's in insert mode